# knockoutjs css binding value when boolean computed property is false/true

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I am binding my currently selected item like this:

The selected item gets visible, but how can I give the unselected items an unselected/default background color? When I set a background color to the template class I do not see anymore the background color set from the selection via mouse click.

Is the problem maybe that I have 2 backgrounds set but none is removed?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <div class="cellContainer" >
            <div class="template" data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem, css: { selected: isSelected }">
                <div data-bind="text: number"></div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.selected {
        background-color: #0094ff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a cascade issue.  Make sure your ".template" style is defined before your ".selected" style in your css file.

Comment: I've absolutely never made that mistake before in my life.  I just completely guessed at what might fix your problem.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `selectItem` method resets `isSelected` on all elements before setting it to true on the argument. A naive implementation could be:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    // Skipped the rest for brevity...

    self.selectItem = function(item) { 

        // Deselect all items first
        for (var i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
            self.items()[i].isSelected(false);
        }

        // Select the argument
        item.isSelected(true);
    };
};
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEvru/) for a demo.

However, it is often easier to keep a reference on the parent view model to the currently selected item, and change the `css` binding to something like:

```
css: { selected: $parent.TheOneSelectedItem().number() == number() }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKrBu/) for the alternate demo.

Comment: give your template divs a default color like NON-White e.g. gray and the selection wont work anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/aKrBu/1/ I set it to yellow.

Comment: @Pascal That's because inline styles normally take precedence over CSS rules with selectors. If you set the default color also through rules [it will work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/DfGsT/), or if you're tied to inline styles for the template you can resort to using `!important` in the rule which [will also work](http://jsfiddle.net/aKrBu/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
.template {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.template.selected {
    background-color: #0094ff;
}
```

It does not look like a knockout issue.